# The condition $\nu\ll\mu$ in the proof of Radon Nykodym theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For simplicity, we assume $\mu,\nu$ are positive and finite measures. The Radon Nykodym theorem states that if $\nu\ll\mu$, then there exists $h\in L^1(X)$ s.t.
$$\nu(E)=\int_Ehd\mu$$
The construction is as follows:
$M=\{g|\int_Eg\leq\nu(E)\}$ for any measurable set $E$. And $h$ is chosen such that $\int_Xhd\mu=\mbox{sup}\{\int_Xgd\mu, g\in M\}$. We need to prove that $\int_Xhd\mu=\nu(X)$, which actually proves $\nu(E)=\int_Ehd\mu$. However, I don't really see where we need $\nu\ll\mu$, could anyone tell me where we need it?

Comment: Well, how are you going to prove $\int h d\mu=\nu(X)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey idon't know where I use the condition I stated and what's the role of it in the theorem

Comment: I'm not sure how you actually prove it, but $\nu \ll \mu$ assures the existence of some $h\in L^1(\mu)$ such that $d\nu = hd\mu$. Take the positive measure associated to the Cantor function, for example.

Comment: @QiyuWen I want to know why it assures the existence of such function